# Oracle: Top 10 most used indexes in the last 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to generate a monthly report where we have to see the top 10 most used indexes and the top 10 least used indexes for our users.

Thus far, i wrote this:

```
SELECT
                        i.owner,
                        i.index_name,
                        c.constraint_type,
                        COUNT(*) AS num_executions
                       
                    FROM
                        dba_hist_sqlstat s
                    JOIN
                        dba_hist_sql_plan p ON s.sql_id = p.sql_id AND s.plan_hash_value =     p.plan_hash_value
                    JOIN
                        dba_indexes i ON p.object_owner = i.owner AND p.object_name =     i.index_name
                    join 
                        dba_hist_snapshot sp on sp.snap_id = s.snap_id
                    LEFT JOIN
                        dba_constraints c ON i.table_owner = c.owner AND i.table_name =     c.table_name AND C.index_name = i.index_name 

                    WHERE
                        s.elapsed_time_total > 0 
                        and i.owner IN ('your_value_here')
                        AND sp.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME >= SYSDATE - 30
                        
                   GROUP BY
                        i.owner, i.index_name,c.constraint_type
                   ORDER BY
                       num_executions asc
                    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;`
```

That's for the top 10 least used, so i would just change the order by of num_executions desc.  My question is, is this the way to get the last 30 days of used indexes?  Or do i have to use something else other than BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME ?

I tried the above and i'm assuming its correct although i have nothing to compare my results to to see if it is truly correct or not.

Comment: "least used" would have to include those not used at all, so you wouldn't be able to use this query. You'd have to start with dba_indexes and then outer join to the query above in a nested block and order by NVL(num_executions,0) to get the least used. As for the "last 30 days" that is what you're doing already. Using dba_hist_snapshot's dates is the right way to set your timeframe when hitting AWR data like this. Although if you use RAC, be sure to include instance_number in the join.

Comment: First, define "most used" and "least used".  You appear to be using a definition based on the number of executions of top SQL statements that used the index.  There are many alternate definitions possible-- for example, amount of I/O performed on the index segment.  If you have a SQL statement that does a nested loop, that statement might have 1 execution but that 1 execution would translate to 10,000 index lookups.  Your current query counts that as 1 index use but another definition would count that as 10,000 index uses.

Comment: What you need all depends on what you plan to do with this information. If you give us more of the big picture, we can advise on best approach.

Comment: @Justin Cave  From my understanding ; these are queries generated by the website used from our users looking up pharmaceutical information on drugs. At first i was tasked to find the top 10 most used sql queries then the top 10 longest queries (all within a month).  From there i was tasked to find the ones with the most indexes used and then least.  Don't know if that clarifies it but i'm assuming they want to see which indexes were being used those most in those top 10 queries, then they wanted to see which where not being used.

Comment: @Paul W thanks, i was thinking my query was strange that it didn't bring up any indexes with 0 but then i thought by virtue of my query this is all tied to users using a query/index so by default it would exclude indexes not being used.

Comment: If I can offer some advice, don't focus on index usage. Instead, focus on long-running queries and tuning them individually. Often it will have nothing to do with indexes. Even if it does, you can't solve perf problems in a blanket way. Every query is its own animal. Since you're exploring AWR data, go ahead and get familiar with `v$active_session_history` (history: `dba_hist_active_sess_history`). That will provide you with what you need to start tackling performance issues from right point of departure.

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi - Your assumption about what your users are asking for may well be correct-- you obviously know your users better than we do.  But it would still likely be helpful to write down your definition of "most used" and "least used" so that everyone is clear what is (and is not) included.  Also, note that AWR captures the most expensive queries so when you go and try to look for least used indexes, you're missing indexes used in less expensive queries.  Also, you're not seeing any usage for maintaining the indexes as a part of doing DML.  I

Comment: If you are trying to figure out if there are indexes you can drop, you'd want to look for indexes that are forcing you to generate I/O to maintain them but aren't being used to improve SELECT query performance.  You're only looking at one side of that balance with your current definition.

Comment: @JustinCave So i revised my query using logical)_reads_total, physical_reads_total, and table_scans_total.  Should i post the query in here for you to see, or edit the answer to include it or edit my original post to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments by @Paul W and @Justin Cave:

"least used" would have to include those not used at all, so you wouldn't be able to use this query. You'd have to start with dba_indexes and then outer join to the query above in a nested block and order by NVL(num_executions,0) to get the least used. As for the "last 30 days" that is what you're doing already. Using dba_hist_snapshot's dates is the right way to set your timeframe when hitting AWR data like this. Although if you use RAC, be sure to include instance_number in the join. –
Paul W

First, define "most used" and "least used". You appear to be using a definition based on the number of executions of top SQL statements that used the index. There are many alternate definitions possible-- for example, amount of I/O performed on the index segment. If you have a SQL statement that does a nested loop, that statement might have 1 execution but that 1 execution would translate to 10,000 index lookups. Your current query counts that as 1 index use but another definition would count that as 10,000 index uses. - Justin Cave

Query for the least amount of indexes used including 0:

```
WITH AllIndexes AS (
SELECT
    i.owner,
    i.index_name,
    c.constraint_type
FROM
    dba_indexes i
LEFT JOIN
    dba_constraints c ON i.table_owner = c.owner AND i.table_name = c.table_name AND c.index_name = i.index_name
WHERE
    i.owner IN ('your_value_here')
)
SELECT
ai.owner,
ai.index_name,
ai.constraint_type,
COALESCE(num_executions, 0) AS num_executions
FROM
AllIndexes ai
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    i.owner,
    i.index_name,
    c.constraint_type,
    COUNT(*) AS num_executions
FROM
    dba_hist_sqlstat s
JOIN
    dba_hist_sql_plan p ON s.sql_id = p.sql_id AND s.plan_hash_value = p.plan_hash_value
JOIN
    dba_indexes i ON p.object_owner = i.owner AND p.object_name = i.index_name
JOIN
    dba_hist_snapshot sp ON sp.snap_id = s.snap_id
LEFT JOIN
    dba_constraints c ON i.table_owner = c.owner AND i.table_name = c.table_name AND c.index_name = i.index_name
WHERE
    s.elapsed_time_total > 0
    AND i.owner IN ('your_value_here')
    AND sp.begin_interval_time >= SYSDATE - 30
GROUP BY
    i.owner, i.index_name, c.constraint_type
) q ON ai.owner = q.owner AND ai.index_name = q.index_name AND     ai.constraint_type = q.constraint_type
ORDER BY
num_executions ASC
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```